# How to get sugarcane in minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've seen sugarcane in Minecraft PE free version, but I cannot collect it, even in survival mode. Can you collect sugarcane in the free version of Minecraft PE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the wiki page on Sugarcane, it is the hardest block to obtain in Minecraft Pocket Edition, due to the worlds not being endless. If there is some that does spawn in your world (sometimes there is none at all), you should be able to destroy it and pick itup, even in the free/demo version of Minecraft Pocket Edition. Also, it only spawns in sandy areas, but the sand HAS to be near water.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work

Comment: It might be a bug.

Comment: My cousin and friends couldn't get it too

Comment: @Bosspvz2 I'm pretty sure it's a bug then. Sorry about that. I hope it gets fixed soon! (I have MCPE also).

Comment: THANK YOU! You gave me some very good knowledge about this game.

Comment: @Bosspvz2 You're very welcome! What platform are you playing it on? I know there's an Android app called PocketInvEditor (there's a free version) that allows you to edit your inventory; you might want to use it to get sugarcane until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Ok. I guess I'll ask the forums(If there is one). Thanks for the idea Timtech.

Answer (score 1):

To get sugarcane, you have to look for a lake, ocean or water source. There is a small chance that there is sugarcane beside the water source, as sugarcane can only grow on the block which is horizontally or vertically beside water. Sugarcane can be used to obtain paper, book and bookshelf.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen it before, but I cannot collect it? Can I collect it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also place one block of sugar cane, hit it with bone meal and it will grow.

Comment: That doesn't work in the PC version, do you have proof it works in Pocket Edition?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i will see if it works... ok